# How to pass data-href in <tr> to jquery script?

Tags: jquery

I want to pop-up a modal window based on a jquery script at http://communitychessclub.com/js/jquery.popupWindow.js

My test page is at http://communitychessclub.com/games_new.php

I am using php to generate a table and I have data-href to trigger the entire table row (tuple) to be clickable to load the game. I have the latest jquery loaded and:

```
<script src="js/jquery.popupWindow.js"></script>
<script>$('.example').popupWindow({centerScreen:1});</script>
```

But the pop-up window is blank, based on this:

```
<tr class="example" data-href="games/game1302.php">
```

How can I fix this line:

```
<script>$('.example').popupWindow({centerScreen:1});</script>

so that it picks up the url specified as data-href of the <tr> ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.example').each(function(){
   $(this).popupWindow({centerScreen:1, windowURL: $(this).data("href")});
});
```

EDIT. Put it in a loop, so `$(this)` is valid. Also, I've noticed you've included the full URL in your `data-href`, so no need to include the `window.location.hostname` now.

Comment: You'll probably need to prepend the whole URL. Include `window.location.hostname` or something. Or include the FULL url in your `data-href` attr.

Comment: I tried <tr class="example" data-href="http://communitychessclub.com/games/game1231.php"> but it still shows a blank pop-up modal.

Comment: This works fine, open your page in browser, then open console either in `firebug` or in `chrome developer` and paste in `$('.example').popupWindow({centerScreen:1, windowURL: window.location.hostname + $(this).data("href")});` then click on any row and it will work. I just checked and it worked, though you have another js error in your code.

Comment: Yeah. But it's 404 which default loads the main page. It's supposed to load the chess game, not the main page.

Comment: Updated @verlager - also, you've got javascript errors elsewhere on your page that you should rectify.

Comment: Sure wish there was a way to actually close the popup by clicking outside the modal. Any ideas?